# Как реализовать работу со статусами заказа?

Tags: архитектура

Вопрос по архитектуре больше. Есть сущность Заказ, у него есть статус - выполнено, собрано, создано и т.п. Есть сущность Статус Заказа. Обе эти сущности представлены таблицами в БД. Как мне лучше огранизовать работу в коде со статусами заказа? Хардкодить константами не хочется, а вот делать выборки по статусам, чтобы например выгрузить в 1с придется.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос в том, в каких рамках вы хотите обсуждать архитектуру? В рамках парадигмы ООП? Или в рамках архитектуры реляционной БД? Если первое, то можно набросать к примеру вот такой код:

```
public class DeliveredOrderCollectionTest
{
    private DataContext storage;

    [SetUp]
    public void setUp()
    {
        this.storage = new DataStorage();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_Order_collection_test()
    {
        IEnumerable<Order> orders = this.storage.Get<IEnumerable<Order>>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(orders);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, orders.Count());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_FormedOrder_collection_test()
    {
        IEnumerable<FormedOrder> formedOrders = this.storage.Get<IEnumerable<FormedOrder>>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(formedOrders);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, formedOrders.Count());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_DeliveredOrder_collection_test()
    {
        IEnumerable<DeliveredOrder> deliveredOrders = this.storage.Get<IEnumerable<DeliveredOrder>>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(deliveredOrders);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, deliveredOrders.Count());
    }
}
```

А если рассуждать с точки зрения деловой логики (используя первичные учетные документы), то статусы заказа можно четко сопоставить с появлением этих самых первичных документов, по мере обработки заказа:

- Клиент набросал товаров в корзину и нажал кнопку оформить - "оформлен"
- В **выписке** банка есть запись об оплате заказа клиентом - "оплачен"
- Склад передал товары, согласно **товарной накладной** в доставку - "сформирован"
- Доставка передала заказ согласно **транспортной накладной** курьеру - "отправлен"
- Курьер вернул подписанную клиентом **транспортную накладную** - "доставлен"

Соответственно у нас в системе (базе) появляются записи об этих первичных документах, сопоставленные с исходным заказом.

Answer (score 0):

Решил сделать так: скрыть работу со статусами заказа за методами, которые их меняют.

```
class Order
  // change status
  reject()
  toDelivery()
  toPay()

  // read status
  isPaid()
  isDelivered()
```